# How does SQL count(distinct) work in this case?

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to find the match no in which Germany played against Poland. This is from https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/soccer-database-exercise/sql-subqueries-exercise-soccer-database-4.php. There are two tables : match_details and soccer_country.  I don't understand how the count(distinct) works in this case. Can someone please clarify? Thanks!

```
SELECT match_no 
FROM match_details 
WHERE team_id = (
    SELECT country_id 
    FROM soccer_country 
    WHERE country_name = 'Germany') 
  OR team_id = (
    SELECT country_id 
    FROM soccer_country 
    WHERE country_name = 'Poland') 
GROUP BY match_no 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT team_id) = 2;
```

Comment: jeez, kind of a convoluted way to do it. Anyways, since every match shows twice (once per team/country), the `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT team_id) = 2` is just checking that the results are showing one match

Comment: Hey Lamak, sorry I still don't get it. So, the count(distinct team_id) is going to check for the distinct team_id for every match_no right? But wouldn't that be the case for every match_no then? Since every team_id is distinct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lamak mentioned, what an ugly consideration for a query, but many ways to approach a query.

As mentioned, counting for (Distinct team_id) makes sure that there are only 2 unique teams.  If there is ever a Cartesian result, you could get repetition of multiple rows showing more than one instance of both teams.  So the count of distinct on the TEAM_ID eliminates that.

Now, that said, Other "team" query data structures I have seen have a single record for the match and a column for EACH TEAM playing the match.  That is easier by a long-shot, but still a relatively easy query.

Break the query down a little, and consider a large scale set of data (not that this, or any sort of even professional league would have such large record counts to give delay with a sql engine).

Your first criteria is games with Germany.  So lets start with that.

```
SELECT 
      md1.match_no 
   FROM 
      match_details md1
         JOIN soccer_country sc1
            on md1.team_id = sc1.country_id
            AND sc1.country_name = 'Germany'
```

So, why even look at any other record/match if Germany is not even part of the match on either side.  Of which this in itself would return 6 matches from the sample data of 51 matches.  So now, all you need to do is join AGAIN to the match details table a second time for only those matches, but ALSO the second team is Poland

```
SELECT 
      md1.match_no 
   FROM 
      match_details md1
         JOIN soccer_country sc1
            on md1.team_id = sc1.country_id
            AND sc1.country_name = 'Germany'
         -- joining again for the same match Germany was already qualified
         JOIN match_details md2
            on md1.match_no = md2.match_no
            -- but we want the OTHER team record since Germany was first team
            and md1.team_id != md2.team_id
            -- and on to the second country table based on the SECOND team ID
            JOIN soccer_country sc2
               on md2.team_id = sc2.country_id
               -- and the second team was Poland
               AND sc2.country_name = 'Poland'
```

Yes, may be a longer query, but by eliminating 45 other matches (again, thinking a LARGE database), you have already saved blowing through tons of data to a very finite set.  And now finishing only those Germany / Poland.  No aggregates, counts, distincts, just direct joins.

**FEEDBACK**

Lets take a look at some BAD sample data... which as all programmers know, there is no such thing (NOT).  Anyhow, lets take a look at these few matches.

```
Match    Team ID    blah
52       Poland     Just put the names here for simplistic purposes
52       Poland
53       Germany
53       Germany
```

If you were to run the query without DISTINCT Teams, both match 52 and 53 would show up... As Poland is one team and appears 2 times for match 52, and similarly Germany 2 times for match 53.  By doing DISTINCT Team, you can see that for each match, there is only 1 team being returned and thus excluded.  Does that help?  Again, no such thing as bad data :)

And yet another sample match where more than 2 teams created

```
Match    Team ID    
54       France     
54       Poland
54       England
55       Hungary
56       Austria
```

In each of these matches, NONE would be returned.  Match 54 has 3 distinct teams, and Match 55 and 56 only have single entry, thus no opponent to compete against.

**2nd FEEDBACK**

To clarify the query.  If you look at the short query for just Germany, that aliased instance of "md1" is already sitting on any given record for a Germany match.  So the second join to the "md2", I only care about the same match, so I can join on the same match_no.  However, in the "md2" alias, the "!=" means NOT EQUAL. ! = logical NOT.  So the join is saying from the MD1, join to the MD2 alias on the same match id.  However, only give me where the teams are NOT the same.  So the first instance holds Germany's team ID (already qualified) and thus give me the secondary team id.  So now I can use the secondary (md2) instance team ID to join to the country to confirm only for Poland.

Does this now clarify things for you?

Comment: Hey DRapp..thanks for your reply. But could we just circle back to this: " counting for (Distinct team_id) makes sure that there are only 2 unique teams. " If we group by match_no and have already specified Germany and Poland for the team_id (from my code), then the result would only be a unique match_no, correct?  What does counting distinct team_id's have to do with it?

Comment: @rahul, see revised answer with DISTINCT clarification.

Comment: Hey DRapp, thanks for clarifying.  One more question: in your code, where you used joins exclusively, could you explain why you had to create md2?SELECT 
      md1.match_no 
   FROM 
      match_details md1
         JOIN soccer_country sc1
            on md1.team_id = sc1.country_id
            AND sc1.country_name = 'Germany' AND 'Poland' . Will, it not work like this?         Also, why do you have to join md1 with md2? and what is the function of the '!' operator? Sorry, I'm just a beginner and so have many doubts...

Comment: @rahul, revised answer again for you.

Comment: Hey, DRapp, yes that explains it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @rahul, glad to make sure you understand WHY instead of just "here... do this..."  Also, welcome to S/O, and for Q&A, if there is any answer as you are going through the site you find helpful, use the up/down arrow respectively.  If you post a question and one is the SOLUTION for you, click the CHECKBOX next to it.  This indicates to others the answer was solved and helps others that may have similar question see what works vs not.